# AJAX Load div ID's children

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, load

Lets say i have this:

```
$('a').each(function() {
    $(this).click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        $('#somediv').load(href + ' #foo');
    });
});
```

Now how would I make it load the inner contents of `#foo` and not the actual div `#foo`

Still not quite sure what I mean?

```
<div id="foo">
    <!-- Load these divs only -->
    <div class="children">bar</div>
    <div class="children">bar</div>
    <div class="children">bar</div>
    <div class="children">bar</div>
    <div class="children">bar</div>
    <!-- // -->
</div>
```

I want to load the inner contents of a div only. Any help is greatly appreciated!

**EDIT: SOLVED**

I used the unwrap method:

```
parent.load(href + ' #' + ident + '', function() {
    $('#'+ident+' > div').children().unwrap();
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this fairly easily if you don't mind using [`$.get`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) and doing the loading parts by hand, something like this:

```
$.get(href, function(html) {
    $('#somediv').html(
        $(html).find('#foo').html()
    );
});
```

This grabs the full chunk of HTML from `href` using `$.get` and then, in the success callback, we find the `id="foo"` element inside the whole pile of HTML, extract its content with [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html) and then copy thing into `#somediv` with the mutator form of `.html()`.

If you know that `#foo` will only contain `<div>` children, then you could try this:

```
$('#somediv').load(href + ' #foo > div');
```

I'm not certain that this will work and I don't have a decent test case set up but the [`.load` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load) indicates that it should work. If `#foo` doesn't contain only `<div>`s then you'll have to come up with something else to use with the [child selector (`>`)](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#child-selectors). Of course, if `#foo` contains text that isn't wrapped in an element, then I think you're stuck with the `$.get` approach above.

Comment: @tfbox: Cool, thanks. Can you check if the child selector works with `.load`? The `$.get` approach is probably safer and more future proof though.

Comment: I haven't tested it but I can't think of any reason why it wouldn't.

Answer (score 2):

You can load only the children of the anchor by using the `>` selector followed by an asterisk:

```
$('#somediv').load(href + ' #foo > *');
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
$(this).click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#somediv').load(href + '#foo *',
    function() {
        $('#somediv #foo').remove();
    });
});
```

Comment: But `*` descends through the whole subtree (see http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/SdC5n/1/ ) rather than just one level so that would probably make a bit of a mess, it also won't catch top level text nodes.

Comment: @mu is too short Thanks for your constructive suggestion. I am a beginner so I need to know a lot more and this kind of suggestion will always expected now and in future. Thanks again. Keep helping.. Pls